# Adding an onblur event to a selectbox div only mockup

Tags: javascript, dom

I can't seem to quite figure out so as to add an onblur event to my css div only selectbox.

The normal onblur method for my wrapper div is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
#container {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
    position:relative;
}
#one {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    background: #C0C0C0;
}
#two {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
}

#commentsbox, ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: default;
    width:194px;
    padding:6px;
}
#commentsbox, ul, li {
    padding: 2px;
}
#commentsbox li:hover{
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
#result {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 206px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function showcommentsbox(){
   document.getElementById("one").style.display="block";
 }
 function hidecommentsbox(){
   document.getElementById("one").style.display="none";
 }

// pick a name that's useful to you:
function textToTextArea (e) {

    e = e ? e : event;
    var text = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text.innerText
}



</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="one" onclick="hidecommentsbox()">
        <ul onclick="textToTextArea(event)" id="commentsbox" onblur="hidecommentsbox()">
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="two"><img src="images/arrow_double.png" onclick="showcommentsbox()"></div>
<br>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: could you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r3E8S/1/

Comment: Pretty sure (at least in some browsers) that blur events don't work on every element type. Blur is mainly for elements that can receive focus (inputs, buttons, etc.). I think blur on div, ul, etc. is spotty (at best). Unfortunately, I don't know (off the top of my head) what the best alternative is. Maybe a "click outside" pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna try to run with my "click outside" idea in the comments, though I normally do these things in jquery.

```
<!--Basically, detect any click that is NOT on your ul and hide the comment box-->
<body onclick="hidecommentsbox()">

<div id="container">
    <div id="one" onclick="hidecommentsbox()">
        <ul onclick="textToTextArea(event)" id="commentsbox">
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

function textToTextArea (e) {

    // Add this line to prevent event bubbling.
    // Normally, events "bubble" up the dom so clicking
    // the ul will ALSO trigger the click event on the "body".
    // This prevents that so that clicks to this element
    // trigger this function, while clicks on anything else
    // hide the comment box.
    e.stopPropagation();

    e = e ? e : event;
    var text = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text.innerText
}
```

This is totally untested and may not be the solution, but it's worth a shot.

Further reading on `event.stopPropagation()` and it's use in "click outside" patterns: http://unencode.blogspot.com/2012/10/javascript-eventstoppropogation.html. (FWIW, "click outside" patterns is, apparently, a name I made up because googling it didn't give me any useful results. But the IDEA is fairly common. There are multiple jquery plugins dedicated to this idea: http://www.jquery4u.com/events/6-jquery-click-event-plugins/.)

EDIT: The intent of the code wasn't immediately obvious to me. I see now what is supposed to happen. So: 1) remove the `e.stopPropagation` from your `textToTextArea` method. 2) Put it in `showcommentsbox` instead (which means you'll need to pass `event` to it).

```
<!--Basically, detect any click that is NOT on your ul and hide the comment box-->
<body onclick="hidecommentsbox()">

    <div id="container">
        <div id="one" onclick="hidecommentsbox()">
            <ul onclick="textToTextArea(event)" id="commentsbox">
              <li>Item 1</li>
              <li>Item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--I misunderstood what was triggering the comment box. This is the click you need
    to prevent propagation on-->
    <div id="two"><img src="images/arrow_double.png" onclick="showcommentsbox(event)"></div>
    <br>
    <textarea id="result"></textarea>
</body>

function textToTextArea (e) {

    e = e ? e : event;
    var text = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text.innerText
}

function showcommentsbox(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    document.getElementById("one").style.display="block";
}
```

Comment: I can't get the popup select box to open with your code. It stays shut forever....

Comment: It actually opens and re-closes faster than you can tell. Which means the event is still bubbling. I think I finally figured out what your code is supposed to be doing. I'll edit the answer accordingly.